# How to create dynamically unique coupon codes in newsletter subscription

Tags: magento-2.1, email, newsletter, coupon-codes

I want to create dynamically unique coupon code for each user that subscribe newsletter and want to embed that code into newsletter email. Is it possible if yes then what is the approach??

I am having magento 2.1.8

Thanks